# I can't import from __init__ in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I want to import socketio from **init**.py file that exist inside my main app folder into main controller that exist inside controllers folder , but i can't do it , an error appears that says:

**ImportError: cannot import name socketio**

here is my app tree:

```
├── add_permissions.txt
├── db_init.py
├── develop
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── abonent.py
│   │   ├── events.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── panel.py
│   │   └── users.py
│   ├── extentions.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── plugins.py
│   ├── requests.py
│   ├── send_sms.py
├── init.sh
├── manage.py
```

The content of my **__init__.py** where i create the app:

```
from flask import Flask

from develop.controllers.abonent import abonent_route
from develop.controllers.panel import panel_route

from flask_principal import identity_loaded, UserNeed, RoleNeed
from flask_login import current_user

from develop.extentions import (
    login_manager,
    toolbar,
    assets_env,
    cache,
    moment,
    principal
)

from develop.models import (
    db,
    User
)

from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(config_object):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    ######## Register Database ########

    db.init_app(app)
    # csrf.init_app(app)

    ######## Register Extentions ########

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    toolbar.init_app(app)
    assets_env.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    principal.init_app(app)

    socketio.init_app(app)

    ######## Register Routes ########

    app.register_blueprint(abonent_route)
    app.register_blueprint(panel_route)

    # Identify the users roles
    @identity_loaded.connect_via(app)
    def on_identity_loaded(sender, identity):
        # Set the identity user object
        identity.user = current_user

        # Add the UserNeed to the identity
        if hasattr(current_user, 'id'):
            identity.provides.add(UserNeed(current_user.id))

        # Add each role to the identity
        if hasattr(current_user, 'roles'):
            for role in current_user.roles:
                identity.provides.add(RoleNeed(role.name))

    return app
```

As you can see i've initiated socketio with the app, no errors tell now.

Inside **panel.py** if i imported socketio from **develop** the error shows whither i used `from develop import socketio` or `from .. import socketio` .

Could any body tells me where is the problem?, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the line in `__init__.py`

```
from develop.controllers.panel import panel_route
```

is before

```
socketio = SocketIO()
```

when any code in `panel.py` like `from develop import socketio` or `from .. import socketio` is executed, there is is nothing called `socketio` in `develop` namespace, the import will fail certainly.

so, you should adjust the position of code lines in `__init__.py` for a fast fix. but it is not still a good practice, the code shall be refactored in the future.

Comment: You are right , now it works i copied the panel_route right above create_app function and the app started without errors , thanks really appreciated ;) .